# Tensorflow Image Classification Python Always Saying Same Answer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wrote an image recognition code for one of my classes. I am classifying "good" and "bad" cardiac ultrasound images. The issue I am having is that the classifier always predicts that the image is "good." I don't have too many images to sort through at the moment, so the accuracy is only about 50%, however I am unsure why the machine always thinks the image is good.

Image Examples:

[Here is a bad image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGJeV.jpg)

[Here is a good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvxqi.jpg)

Any tips? I have provided the code below:

```
#required imports

#using sequential from tensorflow 

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Conv2D

from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D

from keras.layers import Flatten

from keras.layers import Dense


#classification model to be sequential
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))

#output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

#compilation
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#training
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, 
zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory("/home/jovyan/dataset/training_set/", target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory("/home/jovyan/dataset/test_set/", target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 85, epochs = 25, validation_data=test_set, validation_steps=2000)

#predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image=image.load_img("/home/jovyan/dataset/test_set/test_bad_1.jpg", target_size=(64, 64))
test_image=image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image=np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result=classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices

if result[0][0]==1:
    prediction='good'
else:
    prediction='bad'

print(prediction)`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can add examples of images with descriptions of expected result? E.g. "imageA" -  expected good, "imageB" - bad

Comment: Thank you! And yes

Comment: I think the architecture is insufficient, using just one conv layer may not be able to detect the intricate features needed for the model to learn to be able to perform the classification well.

Answer (score 1):

The `test_image` needs to be rescaled by 1./255 the same as `train_datagen` and `test_datagen`.  Since "good" appears to be when there is more white area, the higher values in `test_image` is likely saturating the output activation to always be "good".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Keras, so I will just assume there's no issue in your code and try to give my two cents on your question.

First thing to check is if the dataset is balanced. If there's relatively too many "good" images in the data, the model will just output "good" because it yields better performance than actually predicting in terms of "normal" binary cross-entropy loss.

Therefore, one thing you can try is giving different weights to the two labels (which we refer to as weighted cross-entropy loss): penalizing incorrect answers that were labeled as "good", so that model will now on try to predict "bad" images.

If this doesn't work, you can try [other ways](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) to handle this imbalanced dataset case.

Comment: Hm, my dataset is evenly split, 85 images of "good" and 85 as "bad." Are you suggesting adding more "bad" images?

Comment: Hmm, then that's balanced. Did you check if the accuracy for the training set reaches to ~1.0 over training (overfitting)?

Comment: Well, the model definitely needs a bunch more images, as the accuracy for the training set is barely above 50%. That being said, I NEVER get a "bad" predictor, so I think it must be something else?

Comment: I was referring to the checklist 1 in [this post](https://www.semantics3.com/blog/debugging-neural-networks-a-checklist-ca52e11151ec/), "overfit on a small dataset".